# How do we test a rest api end point that uses azure durable functions?

Tags: api, postman, postman-collection-runner, azure-durable-functions

We have an end point that uses azure functions to get the results. Sometimes we get the results almost instantly and sometimes we get the results after 10 s or 20 s.

I m wondering if there is a better way to test those endpoints using postman or do you use a different tool for testing the end points that relies on the durable functions.This solution works ok but is not reliable always.

```
statusCode = responseCode.code;
var result = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var maxNumberOfTries = 24;
var sleepBetweenTries = 5000;

if (!pm.environment.get("collection_tries")) {
    pm.environment.set("collection_tries", 1);
}

console.log(result);
tests["Status code is 200"] = statusCode == environment["status_OK"];

if (result.abc.length == 0) {
    if (pm.environment.get("collection_tries") <= maxNumberOfTries && statusCode == 200) {
        var tries = parseInt(pm.environment.get("collection_tries"), 10);
        pm.environment.set("collection_tries", tries + 1);
        setTimeout(function () { }, sleepBetweenTries);
        postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestId);
    }
    else {
        pm.environment.unset("collection_tries");
        console.log("Exceeded all attempts to check ABC");
        tests["ABC exist"] = false;
    }
} else {
    pm.environment.unset("collection_tries");
    tests["ABC exist"] = true;
    
    var abcid = result._id;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start an orchestration in your http triggered function the built-in durable functions http response has the following output:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 07:43:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 958
Location: http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/a30d3b1b203e4135b302204b99c989b3?taskHub=DurableDemo&connection=Storage&code=4X/ekkGia/Ng07GHcwLz9CKLClggXjdKKZQ0hQC6pifxteBWvA19jg==
Retry-After: 10

{
  "id": "a30d3b1b203e4135b302204b99c989b3",
  "statusQueryGetUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/a30d3b1b203e4135b302204b99c989b3?taskHub=DurableDemo&connection=Storage&code=4X/ekkGia/Ng07GHcwLz9CKLClggXjdKKZQ0hQC6pifxteBWvA19jg==",
  "sendEventPostUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/a30d3b1b203e4135b302204b99c989b3/raiseEvent/{eventName}?taskHub=DurableDemo&connection=Storage&code=4X/ekkGia/Ng07GHcwLz9CKLClggXjdKKZQ0hQC6pifxteBWvA19jg==",
  "terminatePostUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/a30d3b1b203e4135b302204b99c989b3/terminate?reason={text}&taskHub=DurableDemo&connection=Storage&code=4X/ekkGia/Ng07GHcwLz9CKLClggXjdKKZQ0hQC6pifxteBWvA19jg==",
  "purgeHistoryDeleteUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/a30d3b1b203e4135b302204b99c989b3?taskHub=DurableDemo&connection=Storage&code=4X/ekkGia/Ng07GHcwLz9CKLClggXjdKKZQ0hQC6pifxteBWvA19jg=="
}
```

You then poll the endpoint mentioned in the **Location** header (or the value of the **statusQueryGetUri** property) and apply a wait time which is mentioned in the **Retry-After** header. Once you get a 200 response with the actual result you check the **runtimeStatus** property if that is marked as *Completed* (or *Failed* etc).

This solution is not much different than what you have already. But you're using a bit more built-in functionality from DF.

More info about the DF HTTP API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api

Comment: Thank you Marc, i ll try this out